# How do you strip the message snapshot into the various fields of the map object in flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, snapshot

I am not not able to get the text field in the message object in the new firestore version.
This doesn't work

```
message.data()['text']
```

The code snippet I am working on

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
                final messages = snapshot.data.docs;
                List<Text> messageWidgets = [];
                for (var message in messages) {
                  final messageText = message.data();
                  final messageWidget = Text('$messageText');
                  messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
                }
                return Column(
                  children: messageWidgets,
                );
              },
            ),
```

Comment: post the `messages` collection's schema

Comment: {'text': String, 'sender': String}

Comment: What happens when you access the data like `message.data()["text"]`?

Comment: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try defining the operator '[]'.

Comment: Can you print the contents of `message.data()` in the loop & tell what does it say? There maybe chances that its not a proper map

Comment: Try `message.data().get('text')`.

Comment: The method 'get' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'get'

Comment: I/flutter ( 6469): {sender: xyz@gmail.com, text: Hello}
I/flutter ( 6469): {sender: xyz@gmail.com, text: Hello World}

Comment: what is data on console at `message.data()` ?

Comment: I/flutter ( 6469): {sender: xyz@gmail.com, text: Hello} I/flutter ( 6469): {sender: xyz@gmail.com, text: Hello World}

Answer (score 0):

use message.get(); instead of message.data()['text']

Answer (score 0):

use

```dart
final messageText = (message.data as Map<String, dynamic>)['text'];
```

instead of

```dart
message.data()['text']
```